# dreamweaver cc can't open on my mac 10.10.3

Tags: macos, dreamweaver

Other adobe series can open. but adobe dreamweaver cc can't open on my mac. It doesn't launch even loading screen. i have installed [java](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?locale=en_US) from here.

please help for me.

Comment: You should state your question on Superuser, not on Stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Did you install this using Creative Cloud?  Try uninstalling and resinstalling it.

Also check the Processes tab in Activity Monitor to make sure that another instance isn't running, and if it is, kill that process (click on it and press delete/backspace).

Try killing all the Adobe Processes and then try launch it again.